# Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when using DTO and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dto

My question is fairly simple and already asked in the title.

Here's the context: I've got a domain with entities and repositories. The result of a query is mapped into DTO and sent to the GUI.

The GUI is implemented with WPF and for the mapping, I need classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

My first idea is to have DTO that implement this interface because I foresee a lot of work to map again my DTO into items that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Is it a good practice? Has it pitfalls I haven't seen? What is the "official" good practice for this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DTOs are supposed to be very simple, lightweight, data transfer objects. Because of this, I wouldn't implement anything on them other than their data. Also, I believe if serializing the class to/from a WCF server, the properties need to all be public, so you can't make things like the Id read-only

I would create `Model` classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataErrorInfo` for property changed notification and validation purposes, and have them accept a DTO in the Constructor. Using something like AutoMapper will make mapping a DTO to a Model pretty simple

Comment: +1. a DTO is there only to TRANSFER data. It never changes. It is set with data, then moved between layers. THe moment it accepts updates and does mot - it is not a DTO anymore. Like a vegetarian meal with steak is not a vegetarian meal anymore.

Comment: Ok then, at server side, I work with entities. Then I map the entities into DTO, send it to the client. There, the client map the DTO into the model objects (wich implement INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo. Is it what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is a DTO, there isn't much reason to not implement INPC.

INPC is in every .net impl that I can think of, so you aren't taking extra dependencies that you might want to avoid at both ends of a connection (usually why you would use a DTO)

Using [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver) you can do it with very little code.

Just because your DTO implements that interface, I don't think it makes it any less of a DTO.

The wikipedia definition of DTO says that there is no behavior in a DTO. You have now added behavior in the form of the PropertyChanged event, but given that the whole reason to use a DTO is for remote objects (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx) I am still convinced it is OK.

Fowler states that the point of a DTO is to reduce the number of parameters in a remote call. (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) This doesn't even say that you can't add behavior.

INPC away!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice with WPF would be to use the MVVM pattern (Model-View-ViewModel).
In this instance, your DTO is the Model. You should not pass the Model directly to the View but instead wrap it into a ViewModel that can in turn implement the notification mechanisms.
This way the Model is pure data and doesn't need to worry about what is using it.
Also, there are several frameworks you can use to simplify the mapping work (e.g. [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)).